# How to send several arrays in one via POST?

Tags: php, arrays, post

So, for example, we have an Order Form which includes a cart of products presented as table of inputs:

- Product_id | Product_Quantity | Product_Sum
- 1..................100........................1000
- 2..................200........................2000
- 3..................300........................3000

Plus some other inputs like shipping_cost or customer_name.

How we can send the whole Order Form via POST IF we need to catch the cart on Server as an array of arrays?

So on the other side We should see:

- $_POST[shipping_cost]  = ...
- $_POST[[1,100,1000],[2,200,200],[3,300,3000]]
- $_POST[costomer_name] = ...

Maybe you will offer some another ways to collect and handle this table?

Comment: I could swear this question has been asked before...

Comment: Hi, your html? @cHao LOL, you made my day xD

Comment: Hint: `<input name="products[1][quantity]" value="100">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Post array of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351953/php-post-array-of-array)

Answer (score 1):

POST doesn't contain "arrays". It contains only strings. If you want to send arrays, you'll have to serialize/encode them somehow into a plain string, send that string, then decode/unserialize back to an array.

There is PHP's array naming hack:

```
<input type="text" name="foo[bar][baz]" value="qux" />
```

which would be treated as the equivalent of

```
$_POST = array(
  'foo' => array (
     'baz' => 'qux'
  )
)
```

by PHP.